# Using Jquery with Seleninum RC user-extension.js

Tags: jquery, automation, automated-tests, selenium-rc

I want to include Jquery to our current automation project running Selenium RC ( written in java ).

So we can rely on that JS library for writing our java script code extending the current user-extension.js.

I have heard and searched the web and many say it can be done, by include the source in the user extension o even by adding the library to the core selenium-server.jar.

I have tried both approaches with out luck.

All the time I try to reference Jquery in my java script code, I get a Selenium error "jQuery is not defined".

Maybe am calling the jquery functions wrong inside my user-extension.js, I just don't know.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. 
bye

Answer (score 2):

I use **runScript()** and able to attach jQuery to any page in Selenium RC

[HERE](http://github.com/tszming/Selenium-Google-Scrapper/blob/master/selenium-google-scraper.php)

The script is not Java, but I believe you can use the same approach.

** Use window.jQuery instead of jQuery in the **getEval()** call

Comment: `window.JQuery` or `window.$` saves me

Answer (score 0):

In Selenese (Selenium IDE), I tried  *runScript* with the 1.6.1 jQuery source, and I got it running, if I escape the source before adding it to the testcase html.
Finally, I added *doInjectJQuery* to my user-extions.js

```
Selenium.prototype.doInjectJQuery = function() {
/* include JQuery source here; no escaping needed */
}
```

Now, the following testcase seems to work:

```
<tr>
<td>injectJQuery</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>assertEval</td>
<td>typeof($)</td>
<td>function</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>assertEval</td>
<td>typeof(jQuery)</td>
<td>function</td>
</tr>
```